# Replacing characters with sed

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I want to replace some characters with sed but only if certain condition is fulfilled.

So, if somewhere in the string occurs `\t` it should be replaced with `\`, ie. with backslash and physical tab.
In case where `\\t` occurs, nothing should be done.

A logic would be to replace every `\t` which is not preceded by `\` but I am not sure how to write that regex. Not very good at that stuff and `sed` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -r 's/^\\t|([^\\])\\t/\1\t/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
hello\tworld
foo\\tbar
\tfirst
last\t
last\\t
\\tfirst


$ sed -r 's/^\\t|([^\\])\\t/\1\t/g' file
hello   world
foo\\tbar
        first
last
last\\t
\\tfirst
```

Comment: Thanks for copying 98% from other answers :) but -1 for the fact that this answer doesn't work on Mac 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
sed 's/[^\\]\\t/\\      /' file
```

In the replacement part, it is '2 backslashes+Ctrl-V+Tab'

Comment: -1 this doesn't work. The character before the tab goes missing. e.g. `hello\tworld` becomes `hell\    world`.

Comment: You are right. Didn't notice it since I had some whitespaces before it.